# Credentials for SBT during Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, sbt

I'm trying to publish an SBT build (Scala) using a Azure pipeline.
Locally I can easily do this using `sbt publish` and following lines in the build.sbt:

```
publishTo := Some("name-of-feed" at "https://....pkgs.visualstudio.com/...")
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")
```

However on Azure is my pipeline failing because it doesn't have the .sbt/.credentials file that I have locally.

What is the correct way to fetch the credentials in the pipeline so the build can published?
I don't want to checkin my personal token so there must be some more elegant way.

I see that Azure offers a task `MavenAuthenticate` if you publish using maven. But I can't use that for SBT.
Does any know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward and practical method: Create credentials file on build system with minor effort.

```
 # Creates file in .sbt/.credentials that contains the following content:
 # realm=
 # host=pkgs.dev.azure.com
 # user=your-user
 # password=***
  - script: |
      mkdir -p ~/.sbt
      echo "realm=" >> ~/.sbt/.credentials
      echo "host=pkgs.dev.azure.com" >> ~/.sbt/.credentials
      echo "user=your-user" >> ~/.sbt/.credentials
      echo "password=$(SECURE_PASSWORD)" >> ~/.sbt/.credentials
    displayName: Create credentials file
```

SECURE_PASSWORD is a sensitive variable that should not be exposed.